# Python OpenCV Background Subtraction and Bounding Box

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to using OpenCV and therefore am open to alternative solutions to this problem. I am attempting to obtain the perimeter bounding box of printed circuit boards to crop the ROI from my RGB-D camera to only extract depth data from the region containing the printed circuit board.

Since the camera will be stationary, my initial thought was to use cv2.subtract() using an image of the empty background and an image of a printed circuit board placed on that same background. The output is shown below.

I am now not sure how to obtain the bounding box of the PCB. When I use findContours I obtain 373 different contours which I believe is due to the difference in color of the PCB components, however I only need the perimeter bounding box.

Thanks in advance.
Jadon[image]

EDIT 1: 
img1 is background and img2 is the image with the PCB. I believe the main issue is there are so many contours and I am unsure of how to choose the one to create a perimeter bounding box.

```
diff = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))
cnt = contours[0]

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
img = cv2.rectangle(diff, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please see EDIT 1.

Comment: Use morphology to close holes and remove small white regions in your threshold result. Perhaps even use Otsu thresholding. Then change `cv2.RETR_TREE` to `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`. Then if needed test your contours on area and throw out small contours. Search this forum for other similar topics. There are many examples of doing this.

Comment: have you tried this? https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

Comment: maybe you can also find helpful information on these pages, about eroding, dilating, and rotating: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html and https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful I have it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example where I:

- increase brightness of the image: multiply image by `(255/img.max())`
- apply `threshold` to convert to a binary image (black and white)
- apply `erode` to erase small dots and thin white elements
- apply `dilate` to decrease the size of black holes

At this point, you can use `boundingRect` if your object of interest is the only white area. Unfortunately, in your image, the background at the left side is too bright... Then you can continue:

- alternatively, apply `Canny` - instead of threshold/erode/dilate - to find contours and retrieve a binary image
- apply `findContours` on a binary image (in the code below I redundantly use the Canny-ed image just to expose the example, but it could be the binary image from threshold/erode/dilate, with similar results)
- optionally apply `approxPolyDP` and `hull` to smooth contours (in the example below, I draw the results of these operations, but I do not use them actually)
- calculate `contourArea` and `boundingRect`for each contour
- return only the contour which has the greatest area

The result is:
[image: original image with contours]
(red is `boundingRect`, green is `approxPolyDP` and blue is `hull`)

Almost all of these operations have working examples in [tutorial section in openCV site](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/da8/tutorial_table_of_content_imgproc.html).

### Code

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import random as rng

src = cv.imread("1KbH6.png")
src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# adjust brightness
src_bright = cv.convertScaleAbs(src_gray, alpha = 255.0/src.max(), beta = 0)
# apply threshold
threshold = 100
_, img_thresh = cv.threshold(src_bright, threshold, 255, 0)
# apply erode
erosion_size = 7
erosion_type = cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE
element = cv.getStructuringElement(erosion_type, (2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1), (erosion_size, erosion_size))
img_erosion = cv.erode(img_thresh, element)
# apply dilate
dilatation_size = 17
dilatation_type = cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE
element = cv.getStructuringElement(dilatation_type, (2*dilatation_size + 1, 2*dilatation_size+1), (dilatation_size, dilatation_size))
img_dilate = cv.dilate(img_erosion, element)

# apply canny and find contours
threshold = 100
canny_output = cv.Canny(img_dilate, threshold, threshold * 2)
contours = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# apply approxPolyDP, hull, boundingRect and calculate areas for each contour
contours_poly = [None]*len(contours[1])
boundRect = [None]*len(contours[1])
areas = [None]*len(contours[1])
hull_list = []
for i, c in enumerate(contours[1]):
    contours_poly[i] = cv.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
    hull_list.append(cv.convexHull(contours[1][i]))
    boundRect[i] = cv.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
    areas[i] = cv.contourArea(c)

# set drawing 
drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
# draw only the contour with the greatest area
i = areas.index(max(areas))
color = (0,0,255)
cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, (0,255,0),2)
cv.drawContours(drawing, hull_list, i, (255,0,0),2)
cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
  (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), (0,0,255), 3)

# # Alternatively, you can draw contours with area bigger than some value
# for i in range(len(contours[1])):
#     if areas[i] > 1000:
#         color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
#         cv.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
#         cv.drawContours(drawing, hull_list, i, color)
#         cv.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
#           (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)

cv.imwrite('new.png',cv.add(drawing,src))
cv.imshow('blend',cv.add(drawing,src))
cv.waitKey()

# # If you want to see partial results of image processing
# cv.imshow('src', src)
# cv.imshow('src_bright', src_bright)
# cv.imshow('img_thresh', img_thresh)
# cv.imshow('img_erosion', img_erosion)
# cv.imshow('img_dilate', img_dilate)
# cv.imshow('canny_output', canny_output)
# cv.imshow('drawing',drawing)
```

### Alternative: Chroma key

Another nice approach to improve detection is using something like chroma key: choose a specific background color, convert your color image from RGB to HSV and create a mask (a binary image) filtering by hue. Here is an example: https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html